# Share only Collection on Project Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo db.Here I have a project in which I have 3 Collection so basically:

```
>Project 0
    >Collection 1
    >Collection 2
    >Collection 3
```

I would like to share only Collection 1 with someone, being sure that he does not have access to the other collections, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Project"? Did you enable authentication?

Comment: Are you looking for [collection-level access control](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/core/collection-level-access-control/)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I mean in My cluster i have 3 collection i want to share the acces of only one of theme

Comment: And what do you mean by "access"? Read or Write?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a role and grant this role to the user:

```
use admin
db.runCommand({
   "createRole": "read_collection",
   "privileges": [
      {
         "resource": { "db": "Project", "collection": "Collection 1" },
         "actions": ["find"] // or  ["find", "update", "insert", "remove"] ?
      }
   ]
});

db.createUser({
   user: "readAccount",
   pwd: passwordPrompt(),  // Or  "<cleartext password>"
   roles: [
      { role: "read_collection", db: "admin" }]
})
```

Comment: Ok ! Thank you for your Quick Answer ,but  i just have an email of the person i have to share the collection , where i can put the email on your code ?

Comment: What do you mean? If the person has no access to your MongoDB, then of course he/she cannot access anything. If you just need to send him/her the data, them make a plain "find" and send the output.